# Apparent anomaly in a basic function of R

Tags: r

I have following factor variable:

```
> vect
  [1] C E D E E B C D B E D D C D E C A B B A D C E E C A C C B A B B A A D C C B D B A E B B D E C D C C B D D B D E C B A E C A
 [63] D C E A D C B E B A A C E A A C A B B A A C E D C E E B A B E C E B C E B D
Levels: A B C D E
> 
> str(vect)
 Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 5 4 5 5 2 3 4 2 5 ...
> 
> dput(vect)
structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
), class = "factor")
```

When I try to calculate its mean, I get an error (appropriately). However, if I try to get its standard deviation, I can get it:

```
> mean(vect)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(vect) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> sd(vect)
[1] 1.388954
>
```

I thought mean() and sd() functions should handle factor variables similarly. Where is the problem? Thanks for your comments.

Edit: the version is:

```
> R.version

platform       i486-slackware-linux-gnu    
arch           i486                        
os             linux-gnu                   
system         i486, linux-gnu             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Comment: @Zheyuan I am not getting any warning on my system.

Comment: @RichardScriven That's the whole point. SD function should also make these checks (it should behave similar to mean).

Comment: 3.2.2 : added in question.

Comment: In an own function, I get mean±sd output of  "NA±1.28" , which is obviously odd.

Comment: news(Version == "3.3.0" & grepl("var", Text))  finishes with a blank line output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the currently latest R version 3.3.0, I get the following warning on `sd(vect)`:

```
> sd(vect)
[1] 1.388954
Warning message:
In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

So I assume you are not using the latest R kernel, hence asked you to include `sessionInfo()` or something. Now, you are on R 3.2.2. So we need to go on R CRAN to see what have been changed, **not only in 3.3.0, but in all versions since 3.2.2**. In R CRAN page: https://cran.r-project.org/, there is a **what's new** link:

[image: what's new]

Sorry I put in a picture, because there is no special web address for that link.

The following line is under BUG FIXES in R 3.2.3:

> var() and hence sd() warn about factor arguments which are deprecated now. (PR#16564)

[image: change log]

Let's zoom in:

[image: zoom in]