# Error when aggregating data frame for stand error of the mean: "Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x))"

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset that I'm trying to aggregate to find the mean and the standard error of the mean (SEM) in R, version 3.6.0. I have three genotypes (types) that I have taken measurements on, so I need to take the mean and the SEM of type 1, 2, and 3.

The SEM function is defined here:

```
sem <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
```

Here is the data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  type = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
           2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  measurement = c(12, 14, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 14, 14, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 
                  13, 15, 14, 15, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 15, 12, 12, 15, 
                  13, 14, 13, 14, 12)
)
```

Aggregating for the mean works just fine:

```
mean <- aggregate(data, by=list(data$type), mean)
```

However, when I try to aggregate the SEM, I get an error. I have been able to successfully implement this before with this exact code. What can I do to fix this problem? I have restarted the R session several times; it just doesn't want to work.

```
sem <- aggregate(data, by=list(data$type), sem)

#Resulting error:
Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

Comment: `aggregate(measurement ~ type, data, sem)`.

Comment: And your code works for me: `aggregate(data, by = list(data$type), sem)`. I cannot reproduce the error. Maybe if you change the data set name to something else, `data` is the name of a base R function.

Comment: I can't replicate that error with the data provided. You don't see to have any factors in the sample data here.

Comment: please upgrade your R. This was a error in older version of R which is now a warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369920/apparent-anomaly-in-a-basic-function-of-r